# Problem with overleaf margins

Tags: margins

I have a problem with overleaf margins. it is not fixed on all pages as explained in the picture.
this is my code
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
left=40mm,
right=20mm,
top=30mm,
bottom=20mm,
}
\begin{document}

[image]

Comment: Do you perhaps use `\documentclass[...,twoside,...]{<class>}`?

Comment: Did you see the large red button saying that your project has 30 errors? Correct them!

Comment: no I did not use \documentclass[...,twoside,...]{<class>}

Comment: Okay. Your current display points to `twoside` layout, which either occurs with an explicit use of `twoside`, or when you (for example), use the `book` class. Since you haven't done so, can you please provide your preamble code so we can analyse it and identify what the cause of the problem is?